# What does Z3's simplify tactic do exactly?

Tags: z3

I would like to know what does Z3's tactic `simplify`  exactly do? 
In the [Z3's official document](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorialcontent/guide), it is said :

```
The command (simplify t) displays a possibly simpler expression equivalent to t.
```

Since the functionality of such tactic can usually be summarized via some syntactical rewriting rules like `Not(A or B) --> Not(A) and Not (B)`, can anyone let me know what rewriting does Z3's `simplify` do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documentation that would explain the rewrite rules and there is no list of syntactic rules, neither in the code nor the documentation. To find out what exactly is performed you will have to look at the code. The simplify tactic just runs the `th_rewriter` ([here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/tactic/core/simplify_tactic.cpp#L59)) which applies a number of cross-theory simplifications (all over [th_rewriter.cpp](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/ast/rewriter/th_rewriter.cpp)) and it then calls out to the theory-specific rewriters ([here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/ast/rewriter/th_rewriter.cpp#L164)). For example, for bit-vector terms it will call out to [bv_rewriter::reduce_app_core](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/ast/rewriter/bv_rewriter.cpp#L53).